# how convert urdf to sdf with <preserveFixedJoint> tag

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu, sdf, urdf

installed with robostack
ros2 version: ros-humble.
gazebo -v: Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.12.0 (according to [this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/28657/converting-urdf-to-sdf-preservefixedjoint-not-working) post version should support <preserveFixedJoint> tag)
the problem in this command:

```
gz sdf -p ./hrssd.urdf > ./hrssd.sdf
```

its always generate almost empty sdf file (below) if <preserveFixedJoint> included, if I remove this tags, all working correctly:

```
<sdf version='1.7'>
  <model name='high_range_self_sustainable_drone'>
    <static>0</static>
    <plugin name='thrust_module_plugin' filename='libthrust_module_plugin.so'>
      <thrustLinkNames>thrust_module_1,thrust_module_2,thrust_module_3,thrust_module_4</thrustLinkNames>
    </plugin>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

I tried two different methods for conversion:

1. Semi-manually

   `xacro  ./src/hrssd/xacro/hrssd.urdf.xacro > ./hrssd.urdf`
   `gz sdf -p ./hrssd.urdf > ./hrssd.sdf`
   `ros2 launch hrssd hrssd.launch.py`
   launch.py

   ```
   import os
   from launch import LaunchDescription
   from launch_ros.actions import Node
   from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess

   # Gazebo classic
   def generate_launch_description():
       script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
       current_dir = os.path.dirname(script_dir)

       # Get world
       default_world_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'worlds', 'default.world')

       # Get drone model
       default_model_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'models', 'hrssd_manual.sdf')

       # Launch Gazebo with an empty world, replace this with your world file if needed
       gazebo = ExecuteProcess(
           cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', default_world_path, '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
           output='screen'
       )

       # Node to spawn the robot in Gazebo
       spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                           arguments=['-entity', 'hrssd', '-file', default_model_path],
                           output='screen')

       return LaunchDescription([
           gazebo,
           spawn_entity,
       ])
   ```
2. With gazebo_ros

   `ros2 launch hrssd hrssd2.launch.py`
   hrssd2.launch.py

   ```
   import os
   from launch import LaunchDescription
   from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, DeclareLaunchArgument
   from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
   from launch_ros.actions import Node
   from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

   def generate_launch_description():
       # Define the package name
       package_name = 'hrssd'

       # Define paths
       pkg_dir = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
       default_world_path = os.path.join(pkg_dir, 'worlds', 'default.world')

       # Define launch arguments
       xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_dir, 'xacro', 'hrssd.urdf.xacro')

       # Convert Xacro to URDF
       robot_description = Command(['xacro ', xacro_file])

       # Launch Gazebo with the specified world file
       gazebo = ExecuteProcess(
           cmd=['gazebo', '--verbose', default_world_path, '-s', 'libgazebo_ros_factory.so'],
           output='screen'
       )

       # Node to spawn the robot in Gazebo
       spawn_entity = Node(package='gazebo_ros', executable='spawn_entity.py',
                           arguments=['-entity', 'hrssd', '-topic', 'robot_description'],
                           output='screen')

       # Node to provide the robot_description to the ROS parameter server
       robot_state_publisher = Node(
           package='robot_state_publisher',
           executable='robot_state_publisher',
           output='both',
           parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description}],
       )

       return LaunchDescription([
           gazebo,
           robot_state_publisher,
           spawn_entity,
       ])
   ```

I manually edit sdf file, its worked correctly in gazebo. In rviz2 same story. All working.
So I am pretty sure problem is here:

```
gz sdf -p ./hrssd.urdf > ./hrssd.sdf
```

or in an underlying command that uses gazebo_ros package

usage of tag itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- Macro for a drone motor -->
  <xacro:macro name="thrust_module" params="name parent link_position rotor_area">
    <!-- Link for the motor -->
    <link name="${name}">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="${link_position}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="${rotor_area}"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="${link_position}" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <cylinder length="0.1" radius="${rotor_area}"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
          <mass value="0.2"/>
          <inertia ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1.0" iyz="0.0" izz="1.0"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <!-- Joint connecting the motor to the parent link -->
    <joint name="${name}_joint" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="${link_position}" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <parent link="${parent}"/>
      <child link="${name}"/>
    </joint>
    <!-- Preserving a specific fixed joint -->
    <gazebo reference="${name}_joint">
        <preserveFixedJoint>true</preserveFixedJoint>
    </gazebo>
  </xacro:macro>

</robot>
```

Please, advise. Thank you!